# Не перенеслись картинки для которого использовал плагин PODS с локального сервера на хостинг

Tags: wordpress

На локальном сервере wordpess использовал плагин PODS для создания карточек в слайдере в которыx есть заголовок, описание и картинка. Для картинки использовал текст php, но после того как залил все на хостинг, заголовок и описание остались, а вот картинки не прогрузились. Так же из-за этого поехал и сам слайдер. Вот сайт(в самом конце сайта все находится): http://p87856.hostru07.fornex.host/

```
<img src="<?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail_url(); ?>" alt="" class="blog__img">
```

Comment: А сами картинки на хостинге есть? И по какому адресу они лежат?

Comment: Сами картинки есть на хостинге, но у Вас в `src` нет протокола, если туда добавить  `http://`, то все работает нормально. Каким образом Вы делали перенос?

Comment: Вам в предыдущем вопросе SeVlad дал комментарий со ссылкой на мой пост, как правильно перенести сайт на WordPress. Следуйте инструкции и заканчивайте спамить вопросами.

Comment: @Simon а перенос он делал неправильно, отсюда и все его вопросы

Comment: И кстати, всю Вашу строку можно заменить на `<?php the_post_thumbnail( $size, ['class' => 'blog__img'] ); ?>` только `$size` замените на нужный размер